# Angular authenticate with identityserver and then make http request

Tags: angular

I want to check if the user is authenticated in the session storage using oidc and then make an http request to my api. I am using IdentityServer4 as my oidc provider.

If the 'Auth User' exists in the session storage and the token is not expired I want to make an http request to my api to get user info for the application. This works 100% if the 'Auth User' exists in the session storage, but if it does not and I initiate the authentication with identity, the authentication happens multiple times for reasons I am unable to find.

Here are the methods used in my Auth Service:

```
export class AuthService {
  private manager = new UserManager(getClientSettings());

  private user: User;

  public userAuthenticated: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor(private _router: Router) { }

  getUser(): void {
    if (this.user === null || this.user === undefined) {
      this.manager.getUser().then(user => {
        this.user = user;
        if (this.user === null || this.user === undefined) {
          this.startAuthentication();
        } else {
          this.userAuthenticated.emit(this.user.expired);
        }
      });
    }
  }

  startAuthentication(): Promise<void> {
    return this.manager.signinRedirect();
  }

  completeAuthentication(): Promise<void> {
    if (window !== undefined) {
      return this.manager.signinRedirectCallback().then(user => {
        this.user = user;
        this._router.navigate(['/']);
      });
    }
  }
}
```

User Service

```
export class UserService {
  user: MyUser;

  constructor(private _data: DataService) { }

  getUser(): void {
    if (this.user === undefined) {
      this._data.getUserData().subscribe(res => {
        this.user = res;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Data Service

```
export class DataService {
  apiLocation = 'https://my-api-location/;

  constructor(private _http: HttpClient) { }

  getUserData(): Observable<MyUser> {
    return this._http.get<MyUser>(this.apiLocation + 'end-point');
  }
}
```

App Component

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(
        private _auth: AuthService,
        private _user: UserService
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this._auth.userAuthenticated.subscribe((isExpired) => {
            if (!isExpired) {
                this._user.getUser();
            }
        });

        this._auth.getUser();
    }
}
```